# Executing command via ssh not sourcing ~/.bashrc in Bash 4

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

According to the bash invocation sequence, if a non-interactive, non-login bash shell is invoked via ssh, it's supposed to source `~/.bashrc`. This works just fine with the OS X-shipped Bash 3.2.48(1)-release.

However, when I install bash 4.2.8(2)-release and set that as my login shell, executing a command via ssh (e.g. `ssh <host> <command>`) doesn't source my `~/.bashrc`.

Does anybody know what's wrong, or how I can work around this?

Answer (score 7):

Probably way late, but I've run into this issue, and my solution was adding

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

to my `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Bash 4 installed anymore so I can't test this out (I'm now using Fish), but I have some recollection of trying exactly that and having it not work. From what I recall, the problem is the shell was being invoked as a non-interactive, non-login shell, so it wasn't sourcing any of the usual user-controlled init scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `bash` through ssh with the `--login` option. Like so:

```
ssh <host> bash --login -c "command"
```

Comment: Not applicable in my case. SSH is being run by another utility (specifically, git). I have no control over its invocation.